# Nested CAML operators

Tags: 2010, caml-query, caml

Is it possible to nest query operators other than Or/And, for example, In and Contains operators, so that the query would look for items which would contain any string from my given string collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I think it's not possible.
All Query Schema here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521(v=office.15).aspx

You can dynamically generate big caml query with https://camlex.codeplex.com/ or https://camljs.codeplex.com/